# Background image on button does not appear

Tags: html, css

Im trying to set a background image for a button using a CSS rule but the image doesn't appear.
The button is the one with the class of "todo". The other parts of the rule work because the width and height of the buttons respond accordingly when adjusted but the image does not appear.

I have tried using both "background: url" and "background-image: url" with no results.

The reason for all this is because Im trying to build a todo list and have the button images change depending on if it has been marked complete.

To do this, my plan is to make two different CSS rules with different classes each with their own button background image(one for complete, one for incomplete). When someone marks the item as complete, Im going to add js that changes the items class name to one that matches the css rule for items marked complete.

If anyone knows of an easier way of doing this part suggestions are welcome.

HTML:

```css
.todo{
  background-image: url("../img/check.png");
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/CSS/reset.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/CSS/style.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
           <header>
               <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add an item"/>
               <button id="button"  type="button">Add item </button>
            </header>
               <div id="list">
    
         <!–– Below li is a template literal added with js. ––>

                  `<li>
                    <div class="item">
                       <div class="complete">
                        <button id="complete" class="todo">Complete</button>
                       </div>
    
                       <p class="text">${value}</p>
    
                        <div class="remove">
                           <button id="` + randomId  +`" class="todo"></button>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                   </li>`;
    
                </div>
            </div>
         <script src="resources/JS/app.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Both your HTML and CSS are correct. Are you sure that you have a folder called `img` at the *parent* level of your CSS file? And that the folder contains a file called `check.png`? And that it has been uploaded to the server? And that you've not cached the scripts (try `CTRL + F5`)?

Comment: I actually haven't uploaded it yet so everything is just on my computer. My directory  goes Desktop/App Folder/Img/check.png.

Comment: "_My directory goes Desktop/App Folder/Img/check.png_ " The folder `Img` is capitalised in your comment but not in your code _ Both folders should be named identically_ including upper or lower case

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my comment. My bad. The folder and image names  actually are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to this for the background image in any component:

```
.todo {
background-image: url(../../img/check.png);
background-position: Xpx Xpx;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```